# How to instrument only specific classes inside a jar in Cobertura?

Tags: ant, cobertura

Cobertura's documentation gives the following example to show how instrumentation can be done on classes inside a jar file that is on Cobertura's classpath.

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
    ...........       
    <fileset dir="../lib">
        <include name="myjar.jar" />
    </fileset>
    ...........
</cobertura-instrument>
```

This approach will instrument all the classes inside the specified jar.

How can I instrument only specified class files inside the jar?

Comment: Have you tried to unzip the current jar file before you call cobertura-instrumented and then add the files you want. Or generate a new jar file with the classes you want tou instrument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cobertura-instrument` task has two sub-tasks which may do the trick (didn't have the possibility to try it out):

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
  <includeClasses regex=".*" />
  <excludeClasses regex=".*\.Test.*" />
  <!-- ... -->
</cobertura-instrument>
```